# Isn't android fragment, an equivalent of a Partial View in Asp.Net Core MVC?

Tags: android, razor, asp.net-core

Seems [fragments](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments) reacts to a user event only.

> What is the Android component used for, breaking an activity into
>   multiple sub-components?

Just for sake of maintainability of `UI code` in Android.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know exactly what you mean by "reacts to user events only". You can also have *headless fragments* which don't have an UI.

You can use fragments for your intention. You can communicate between the fragments via your activity (which holds the fragments).

Speaking of clean code maybe you want to take a look at the Architecture Components & MVVM